# Jmeter - Variables from input file to output file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, csv-file

Is there a way to write variables from csv input file to the .csv output file?

i have input.csv with

```
planID |planNum
----   |----
1      | 123456
```

Also, I have user defined variable: varToFlexibleFileWriter, value: "some value"

I am using flexible File writer to write output file
In Record each sample as, I have : `${varToFlexibleFileWriter}|\t|${planNum}|\r\n`

but in outfile I see:

```
userDefinedVar | planNum
some value     | ${planNum}
```

User defined variable is displayed as expected, but there is no value for planNum.

Is there a way to make flexible file writer to write variable values from input file? Thanks

Comment: You can use csv configuration in jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some extra configuration so Flexible File Writer could save your `planNum` variable.

1. Add the next line to `user.properties` file (it is located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   sample_variables=planNum
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. Alternatively you can define the property by passing it via `-J` command-line argument like:

   jmeter -Jsample_variables=planNum -n -t yourplan.jmx -l results.jtl
2. Use `variable#0` instead of `${planNum}` in the Flexible File Writer

References:

- [Saving JMeter Variables with Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/#Saving-JMeter-Variables-with-Flexible-File-Writer)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

Every answer I see in all the internet avoids the main question!

**How does one write a dynamic values to the output?**

Clearly the original author of the thread wanted to submit changing values into the output. (csv, etc...)
From every answer I see, the end result is **NO**, you cannot write changing values to Flexible File Writer!!!

If this had been the **intent** of the developer, they would had allowed custom ${vars} to be used in the plugin.
EVERYTHING is static output. The only dynamic values are the tiny subset of vars that can be used and cannot be modified.

Comment: How does this add to the accepted answer?